# How to properly align items in a page? [HTML]

Tags: html, angularjs, position, alignment

I have this page:
[image]

And by pressing the "Add new Company" button it opens a form like this:
[image]

I would like to have the table to be in the center always, the "Add" button and the form should be in the right side of the table and shouldn't move it down, and the "search" button opens another table by the left side of the page without moving anything.

how it can be done using CSS,HTML and Angular ?
Codes by request:

this code is right before the "table" code.

```html
<button ng-click="g.createCompanyShow()">
  <img alt="Create" src="../Ico/+.png" width="200px" height="20px">
 </button>
 <div ng-show="g.createCompanyButton">
  <div ng-controller="createCompanyCTRL as c" ng-app="myApp">
   <ng-include src="'createCompany.html'"></ng-include>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you include the codes necessary to reproduce that pictures?

Comment: amm it's kind of a long code, what part exactly? the table part?

Comment: The code on how you are showing the form

Comment: @Swellar added it to the main message

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS commands like: "position: absolute" and the "margin-left/right" I got the result I wanted.